# PYTHON - Merge two dataframes on date indexes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I am wanting to merge two dataframes (PRIM_recs and SECO_recs) on common date indexes.

PRIM_recs =

```
                    Hsig    Thsig   Hrms    Hmax    Tc      Tz
1976-10-31 15:00:00 0.93    8.21    0.64    1.75    2.82    5.42...
1976-11-01 03:00:00 1.34    6.08    0.93    2.11    3.14    4.56...
1976-11-01 15:00:00 1.39    6.01    0.99    2.40    2.80    4.38...
1976-11-02 03:00:00 1.30    6.35    0.93    2.18    3.24    4.91...
1976-11-02 15:00:00 1.31    9.91    0.91    2.18    3.36    6.71...
     :     :     :     :     :     :     :     :     :     :
2017-05-20 04:00:00 1.442527    7.407674    1.050540    2.61    5.868847    5.891295...
2017-05-20 04:30:00 1.555761    6.361763    1.108141    3.16    5.758905    5.770841...
2017-05-20 05:00:00 1.563837    7.925315    1.143206    2.31    6.160781    6.181728...
2017-05-20 05:30:00 1.637766    7.488912    1.154951    2.66    5.647312    5.672689...
2017-05-20 06:00:00 1.622043    7.154768    1.146905    2.55    5.679639    5.714273...
```

SECO_recs =

```
                     Spc
1976-10-31 15:00:00 [0.0124, 0.0096, 0.0325, 0.1562, 0.4494, 0.738...
1976-11-01 03:00:00 [0.0254, 0.0299, 0.0273, 0.1229, 0.596, 0.9833...
1976-11-01 15:00:00 [0.0226, 0.0236, 0.0269, 0.085, 0.4163, 0.8011...
1976-11-02 03:00:00 [0.0132, 0.0154, 0.0172, 0.1336, 0.4743, 0.694...
1976-11-02 15:00:00 [0.0124, 0.0169, 0.028, 0.5028, 1.4503, 1.6055...
     :     :     :     :     :     :     :     :     :     :
2017-05-20 04:00:00 [5.374061e-13, 1.2720002e-06, 0.00052255474, 0...
2017-05-20 04:30:00 [1.2021946e-12, 3.3477074e-06, 0.0014435094, 0...
2017-05-20 05:00:00 [1.2236685e-13, 5.018357e-07, 0.00023753957, 0...
2017-05-20 05:30:00 [3.5527579e-13, 1.1004944e-06, 0.0005480177, 0...
2017-05-20 06:00:00 [4.968573e-13, 1.4969078e-06, 0.00065009575, 0...
```

I preform the merge using the following statement:

```
# Merge PRIM data with SECO data on common dates
df_PRIM_SECO = pd.merge(PRIM_recs, SECO_recs, left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

This gives me a merged dataframe (df_PRIM_SECO), **but this df contains a number of duplicate rows**!

PRIM length   =  364229
SECO length   =  364228
Merged length =  364271

To resolve this I currently include the following statement:

```
# Need to drop any duplicate index values that resulted from the merge
df_PRIM_SECO = df_PRIM_SECO.loc[~df_PRIM_SECO.index.duplicated(keep='first')]
```

This gives me the required dataframe (minus the duplicates)!

PRIM length   =  364229
SECO length   =  364228
Merged length =  364202

The fewer number of rows in df_PRIM_SECO (than either PRIM_recs or SECO_recs) results from the original dataframes having some non-common dates which are omitted by the merge.

My question is:

Although I now have the result I want, **why did my merge statement produce some duplicate rows**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Why did my merge statement produce some duplicate rows?

**TLDR:** Pandas when merging automatically merges all possible combinations of duplicate keys.

First off, you are performing an inner merge (default `how` parameter), where if the key (in your case, the index) is not in both sets, it is excluded from the final merge.

Here, let's say that we are merging on a column with strings as keys for simplicity, as opposed to timestamp indices. For example,

```
d1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['a', 'b'], 'n1': [1,2]})
d2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['b', 'c'], 'n2': [8,9]})

pd.merge(d1,d2, on='A')
```

produces

```
    A   n1  n2
0   b   2   8
```

As we can see, `'b'` was the only key that resided in both columns, so when merged, it only keeps those instances. Thus the resulting size of the dataframe was 1. If we changed `d2` slightly

```
d1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['a', 'b'], 'n1': [1,2]})
d2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['b', 'b'], 'n2': [8,9]}) # change instance 'c' to 'b'

pd.merge(d1,d2, on='A')
```

the merge instead produces

```
    A   n1  n2
0   b   2   8
1   b   2   9
```

Makes sense, 2 instances of `'b'` in `'d2'`, therefore 2 instances of `'b'` after the merge. But what if we now changed `d1` slightly

```
d1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['a', 'b', 'b'], 'n1': [1,2,3]}) # added another instance of b
d2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['b', 'b'], 'n2': [8,9]})
```

Ok so following the same logic, there are 2 instances of `'b'` in each dataframe, and we are doing an inner merge, so there should be 2 instances of `'b'` after the merge... right?

This is incorrect as each `'b'` now must be merged on all instances of `'b'`. To show,

```
pd.merge(d1,d2, on='A')

    A   n1  n2
0   b   2   8
1   b   2   9
2   b   3   8
3   b   3   9
```

So now the size is 4. Upon inspection, `'b' 2` merged not only with `'b' 8` but also with `'b' 9`. This is also the case with `'b' 3`. If we note that the sizes of `d1` and `d2` were 3 and 2 respectively, we obtained a dataframe with a size **larger than both of them**. So this is happening because multiple instances of the category are in both dataframes prior to the merge. As you state, you resolve the size issue by dropping the duplicated values after the merge. You are keeping the first values that are duplicated and discarding the rest. In this example then,

```
pd.merge(d1,d2, on='A').drop_duplicates(subset='A', keep='first')

    A   n1  n2
0   b   2   8
```

As we can see, this returns the same output from the first example merge. It can be uncomfortable that after a merge, the size of the outputted dataframe is larger because of this duplication on the keys.

To ease this feeling, you can drop the duplicate values prior to the merge instead. Using the dataframes with the added instance of `'b'`, if we perform the merge

```
d1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['a', 'b', 'b'], 'n1': [1,2,3]}).drop_duplicates(subset='A', keep='first')
d2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['b', 'b'], 'n2': [8,9]})

pd.merge(d1,d2, on='A')
```

we obtain the same output as the original second merge we performed outlined above

```
    A   n1  n2
0   b   2   8
1   b   2   9
```

Finally, if we drop duplicates from both dataframes, we obtain our original first merge output,

```
d1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['a', 'b', 'b'], 'n1': [1,2,3]}).drop_duplicates(subset='A', keep='first')
d2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['b', 'b'], 'n2': [8,9]}).drop_duplicates(subset='A', keep='first')

pd.merge(d1,d2, on='A')

    A   n1  n2
0   b   2   8
```

So, why does the merge statement produce duplicate rows? As shown, it has to do with the mappings of the keys. **Pandas when merging automatically merges all possible combinations of duplicate keys. If it did not do this, it would be a much less flexible operation.** Instead you can specify before (or after) the merge to drop the duplicates so that this does not happen.

On larger dataframes, with many duplicate key values, this operation of making all the possible combinations can quickly expand the resulting dataframe by a lot (try it out, add a couple more instances of `'b'` in both `d1` and `d2`). However in your case there seems to be only a few duplicates in each dataframe. If there were a lot more duplicates, I would advise dropping duplicates prior to the merge, but it does not seem to be a big issue in your case.

Comment: bbd108, thank you for your excellent explanation. Pandas continues to amaze me with its power (and its nuances)!

Comment: Great, I'm glad I could help. Pandas is quite powerful and flexible. If this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.